# Major issue in nv.d3.js

Tags: javascript

I am experiencing something strange! I have used the source code for this: http://nvd3.org/ghpages/stackedArea.html#source_code

I have added this two lines at the begining:

```
<script src="data/nv.d3.css"></script>
<script src="data/nv.d3.js"></script>
```

But when I run it it says that:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in nv.d3.css. Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/css

How it is possible that inside a added css we have syntax error! I have downloaded the pakage from the web site.
Any idea?

Comment: why not looking for the error message using the awesomeness of google? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562521/resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-x-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should import CSS files with `<link href="data/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`, not with `<script>`.

Answer (score 0):

Css file needs to be referenced  in a `<link />` tag