# use Less without localhost / server, client-side, browser

Tags: css, less, client-side

I'm trying to work with bootstrap for the first time and so far it works ok.

However i'm at the media queries that require Less.
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

Right now i have this in the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.less">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/less-1.7.4.min.js"></script>
```

And this is the less file:

```
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { 
    background-color: red;
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { 
    background-color: green;
}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { 
    background-color: blue;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "file:///Users/doekewartena/Downloads/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/custom.less".
```

Which is related to this:
[LESS css variable not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269856/less-css-variable-not-working)

What i'm wondering. Does less needs to run on a server / localhost, and if so why?

I use the chrome browser.

Comment: Correct link to a Less file should look like `<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/custom.less" />`. Though it should work the way you wrote it anyway ("Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain" is actually a warning not a error). Either way, it would be helpful if you'd specify more details about your setup (specifically the browser you use since `file://` serving [heavily depends](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18531239/2712740) on this).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/x-c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562521/resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-x-c)

Comment: Thanks @seven-phases-max the /less fixed it.

Comment: And it is possible to run without a webserver. This is not clear in the other topics flagged here as possible duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can run on the client-side/browser as it is written in pure JavaScript (using less.js).
**Read** the [Getting started tutorial](http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage) about client-side usage.

Copy and paste code from that page as writing it yourself is hazardous.

Common mistakes are:

- The link rel must be `rel="stylesheet/less"` and **NOT** `rel="stylesheet"` !
- Respect the **load order** as the less JavaScript requires the .less stylesheets files to be loaded before it runs in order to process them !
- Of course make sure the file paths are correct...

I recommend to test with the simplest scenario possible (one variable, one less file).